# N-to-1 parameterizable multiplexer code when N=1

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to code for a N-to-1 Parameterizable Multiplexer design where `N` could be 1-8. this is what I have got so far:

```
module param_mux
#(
   parameter N = 2
)
(
   input  logic [3:0] i_data [N-1:0],
   input  logic [2:0] sel, //the select pin is fixed at 3 bits since maximum N will be 8
   output logic [3:0] o_data
);
   assign o_data = i_data[sel];

endmodule
```

This seem to work except when N=1. For N=1, I would like the `o_data` to be 'b0 when `sel` is not 0. i.e:

```
if sel == 0, then o_data = i_data[0]  
else o_data = 'b0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want different behavior based on a `parameter` value, you can use a `generate` `if` statement.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 27.5 *Conditional generate constructs*:

```
module param_mux
#(
   parameter N = 2
)
(
   input  logic [3:0] i_data [N-1:0],
   input  logic [2:0] sel, //the select pin is fixed at 3 bits since maximum N will be 8
   output logic [3:0] o_data
);

if (N == 1) begin
   assign o_data = (sel) ? '0 : i_data[0];
end else begin
   assign o_data = i_data[sel];
end

endmodule
```

The `generate/endgenerate` keywords are optional.